# How to structure, multiple single page forms and handle them in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an html form using express-handlebars inside a loop that gets rendered a certain amount of times based off how many users there are assigned to a group.
So if there are 5 users the below code between the "#Each" gets loaded 5 times.

How do I structure this so that I can Post it back to node and write it to mongoDB in terms of what I use for the id and name.

I couldn't find anything related, if there's anything on here, please link it :)

```
<form action="/users/rsvp" method="POST">
                {{#each docs}}
                <div class="card border-secondary mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header"></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{this.name}}</h4>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" id="{{this._id}}"
                                name="{{this._id}}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="{{this.id}}">
                                Attenting
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" id="{{this._id}}"
                                name="{{this._id}}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="{{this._id}}">
                                Not Attenting
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DietaryRequirements"></label>
                            <input type="text" id="DietaryRequirements" name="DietaryRequirements" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Dietary Requirements" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{/each}}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                    RSVP
                </button>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, all the users' form are rendered within 1 `<form>`, which will cause a lot of duplicate fields on DietaryRequirements and of course the server cannot figure out which field is for which user. You can simply break it up so that each user has a separate , and pass the user's ID through a hidden input. E.g.:

```
{{#each docs}}
<form action="/users/rsvp" method="POST">
    <!-- Your Form Content, name=attending and name=dietaryRequirements -->

    <input type="hidden" value="{{this._id}}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        RSVP
    </button>

</form>
{{/each}}
```

**OR**

If you really want a single form for the whole group of user, you can utilize the [extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended) setting on body parser, which allows submission of nested object through HTML, in that case you write something similar to:

```html
<form action="/users/rsvp" method="POST">
    {{#each docs}}
    <div class="card border-secondary mb-3">
        <div class="card-header"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{this.name}}</h4>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1" id="user-{{this._id}}-attending"
                    name="user[{{this._id}}][attending]">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="user-{{this._id}}-attending">
                    Attenting
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="0" id="user-{{this._id}}-not-attending"
                    name="user[{{this._id}}][attending]">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="user-{{this._id}}-not-attending">
                    Not Attenting
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user-{{this._id}}-dietary"></label>
                <input type="text" id="user-{{this._id}}-dietary" name="user[{{this._id}}][dietaryRequirements]" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Dietary Requirements" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        RSVP
    </button>

</form>
```

Notice the `name` s has a notation of a[b][c], and also the `id` and `for` should have unique pairings on each page which have been fixed as well.

If you have set body parser extended to true, you should get for req.body:

```js
{
    user: {
        '10': {
            attending: '1',
            dietaryRequirements: 'Meaty'
        },
        '11': {
            attending: '0',
            dietaryRequirements: 'N/A'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. If I wanted to iterate through this, could that just be done in a for/foreach loop?